# What are 2 parameters do in is_callable() function in php?

Tags: php, callable

I am new to php can anyone tell what the last 2 parameters do in **is_callable()** function in php ?

In the following examples it returns same result with **true** and **false**

First with **false**

```
function hello(){
    return "Hello";
}

$x = 'hello';
echo is_callable($x,false);
```

> Return true

Now with **true**

```
function hello(){
    return "Hello";
}

$x = 'hello';
echo is_callable($x,true);
```

> Returns true

What basically the last two parameters are used for in this function.

is_callable(parOne,parTwo,parThree);

I have read about this on php.net but failed to understand. Can anyone tell for what the last two parameters are used in this function ?

Answer (score 2):

When the second argument is `true`, it doesn't check whether the first argument actually names an existing function, just whether it has the appropriate syntax to be used to try to call a function. That means it's either a string, or an array whose first element is an object and second element is a string.

For instance:

```
is_callable('hellox', false);
```

returns `FALSE` because there's no `hellox()` function, but:

```
is_callable('hellox', true);
```

returns `TRUE` because it could be the name of a function.

But

```
is_callable(1.23, true);
```

returns `FALSE` because a number can't be used as a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(
        ["is_callable(null, true)" => [(int)is_callable(null, true), "because null can't store callable name"],
        "is_callable(7,    true)"  =>  [(int)is_callable(7,    true), "because integer can't store callable name"],
        "is_callable('so', true)"  => [(int)is_callable('so', true), "because callable name can be saved in string"],

         "is_callable('so', false)"  => [(int)is_callable('so', false), "because such callable doesn't exists in code"],
         "is_callable('is_callable', false)"  => [(int)is_callable('is_callable', false), "because such callable exists and can be executed"],
        ]
        );
echo '</pre>';
```

So in short - parameter `$syntax_only = true` just does type checking - checks if callable name CAN be stored in input variable. While `false` - additionally checks if such callable really exists in code and can be executed.